# How do I get my php form to display a succes notice?

Tags: php, html, contact-form

This is my first post here. I'm really hoping you can help me out!

I just implemented a bootstrap contact form on my website. The form is set to redirect to another website if the mail is sent successfully. I really want it to just show a notice saying "E-mail sent" or something like that.

I do realize that

`header('Location: http://address-of-confirmation-page.html');
    exit();`

is what needs to be changed, i just don't know how to change it to the success message

Here's my code:

The PHP

```html
/* Set e-mail recipient */
$myemail = "your-email@gmail.com";

/* Check all form inputs using check_input function */
$name = check_input($_POST['inputName'], "Your Name");
$email = check_input($_POST['inputEmail'], "Your E-mail Address");
$subject = check_input($_POST['inputSubject'], "Message Subject");
$message = check_input($_POST['inputMessage'], "Your Message");

/* If e-mail is not valid show error message */
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
{
show_error("Invalid e-mail address");
}
/* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */

$subject = "Someone has sent you a message";

$message = "

Someone has sent you a message using your contac form:

Name: $name
Email: $email
Subject: $subject

Message:
$message

";

/* Send the message using mail() function */
mail($myemail, $subject, $message);

/* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
header('Location: http://address-of-confirmation-page.html');
exit();

/* Functions we used */
function check_input($data, $problem='')
{
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
{
show_error($problem);
}
return $data;
}

function show_error($myError)
{
?>
<html>
<body>

<p>Please correct the following error:</p>
<strong><?php echo $myError; ?></strong>
<p>Hit the back button and try again</p>

</body>
</html>
```

The HTML

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="panel panel-default" style="margin:0 auto;width:500px">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h2 class="panel-title">Contact Form</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <form name="contactform" method="post" action="php/contact.php" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputName" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name</label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" name="inputName" placeholder="Your Name">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email</label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" name="inputEmail" placeholder="Your Email">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputSubject" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Subject</label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSubject" name="inputSubject" placeholder="Subject Message">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputPassword1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Message</label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                  <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" id="inputMessage" name="inputMessage" placeholder="Your message..."></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                    Send Message
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Bootstrap already has success messages like this one, which would be nice to have:

```html
<div class="bs-example">
    <div class="alert alert-success fade in">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
        <strong>Success!</strong> Your message has been sent successfully.
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can use

```
header('Location: http://current-page.php?success');
```

And put this somewhere suitable

```
if(isset($_GET['success'])){
    //echo the success message
}
```

I guess this is kinda "hacky" but it works.

I would also recommend jQuery to submit the form to an external page and have it return a success and have jQuery return a success flag and then dynamically show the success message on the page. You can do some research on that, rather than using PHP to do this.

Comment: He's already using a header `header('Location: http://address-of-confirmation-page.html');
exit();` - Re-read the question and look at their entire code (again). My guess; outputting before header.

Comment: I may have misunderstood but I believe he wants to, rather than going to another page, stay on the current page but output the bootstrap error message?

Comment: *duh*, my mistake, long day lol. Yeah you're right. OP says that boostrap has that success message. No idea why it's not working for them. Maybe not using it correctly. Wouldn't take no more than a few minutes on Google for them to look that up. I have used bootstrap myself before. They should visit http://bootsnipp.com/ there's a whole bunch of cool snippets on there. As does the bootstrap site itself.

Comment: I think OP is looking for a way to implement this message on the page that's processing the mail rather than redirecting to another page, which is what I have suggested. The bootstrap message is what OP wants to implement, it's not been done yet. I'd be better if OP used jQuery ajax requests if he wants the success message to display dynamically rather than using PHP as it would involve something a little hacky like I suggested above.

Comment: Ajax for sure, would be a better solution by far.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set the "http://address-of-confirmation-page.html" page to a simple thank you page? This wouldn't involve any clever scripting. Its basic, but it fits with your script!

so change :

```
    /* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
header('Location: http://address-of-confirmation-page.html');
exit();
```

to

```
    /* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
header('Location: http://yourwebsite.com/thank_you.php');
exit();
```

and thank_you.php would be :

```
<div class="bs-example">
<div class="alert alert-success fade in">
    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
    <strong>Success!</strong> Your message has been sent successfully.
</div>
</div>
```

Does that answer your question, or is that too simplistic of a solution?

Comment: I know this would work, i just don't think its a very nice solution to have the user of the website shift back and forth between that page. There's no functional reason why the user should be "kicked off" the website for filling out a contact form.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it, and it's not so hard (and easy to maintain) is using Ajax like the other suggested.

#### Javascript/jQuery

First add an id to the form element, let's say `#contact-form`, then let's send the form via ajax:

```
$("#contact-form").submit(function(e) {
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: php/contact.php,
       data: $("#contact-form").serialize(),
       success: function(data){
          $('#message')
            .addClass('alert-'+ data.status)
            .append(data.message);
       }
    );
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

#### HTML

Hide the message by default, and let's show the correct message depending of the p

```
    <div id="message" class="alert" style="display: none;">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
    </div>

<!-- Your contact form here -->
```

#### PHP

That's your homework, the script should be waiting a response in json, something like:

```
$result = array(
   'status' =>  // success | error ,
   'message' => // 'Success Message' |  'validation message'
);
echo json_encode($result);
```